# Python decorator internally calls wrong function

Tags: python, twisted, decorator

We have implemented a twisted web api.

To handle auth we have used a decorator that we wrap some routes with.

```
@requires_auth(roles=[Roles.Admin])
def get_secret_stuff(request):
    return 42
```

The `requires_auth` wrapper is implemented as follows.

```
def requires_auth(roles):
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapped_f(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # If the user is authenticated then...
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap
```

The issue is if there are multiple routes with this decorator, then a call to
any of them results in the latest route to be decorated being called.

This is obviously not what I wanted and counter to my understanding of how decorators should work.
I added some print statements to the code to try and figure it out:

```
def requires_auth(roles):
    def wrap(f):
        print(f) # This shows that the decorator is being called correctly once per each
                 # route that is decorated
        def wrapped_f(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # If the user is authenticated then...
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap
```

In case it is important, I am using twisted's inlineCallbacks for some of these routes, as well as twisted web's `@app.route(url, methods)` decorator for all of these routes.

Thank you for reading :)

EDIT:
I removed the default argument to the constructor as I was told this was a bad idea :)

EDIT: Here is a minimal example that illustrates the problem:

```
from klein import Klein
import json
app = Klein()

def requires_auth(roles):
    def wrap(f):
        print('inside the first clojure with f=%s' % str(f))
        def wrapped_f(request, *args, **kwargs):
            print('inside the second closure with f=%s' % str(f))
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap

@app.route('/thing_a')
@requires_auth(roles=['user'])
def get_a(request):
    return json.dumps({'thing A': 'hello'})

@app.route('/thing_b')
@requires_auth(roles=['admin'])
def get_b(request):
    return json.dumps({'thing B': 'goodbye'})

app.run('0.0.0.0', 8080)
```

Going to the route '/thing_a' results in the json from route_b

Comment: Shouldn't `wrap` return `wrapped_f`?

Comment: Yeah sorry I mistakenly left that out, updated.

Comment: You have `@requires_auth` yet `def require_auth`... Note the `s`

Comment: Once again, this was a typo :p

Comment: Could you print `f` at the beginning and end of `wrapped_f` to ensure that it is still the same?

Comment: I tried that and it is NOT the same. EDIT: f is the same while inside wrapped_f, however the f inside wrapped_f is not the same as the f inside wrap

Comment: Could you then rename `f` to `original_f` or something? You should just need to rename it twice, i.e. once in the `wrap` definition and in the call of the inner `return`. If that fixes it, you are overwriting your `f` somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from functools import wraps

def require_auth(roles=(Roles.USER,), *args, **kwargs):

    def call(f, *args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    def deco(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped_f(request, *a, **kw):
            # do your authentication here
            return call(f, request, *a, **kw)

        return wrapped_f

    return deco
```

Comment: It was @wraps that fixed it. This still works even without the call :)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using mutable arguments (e.g. lists) as default parameters to any function or method. [More on why this is a bad idea](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/01/16/python-insight-beware-of-mutable-default-values-for-arguments/).

I can't confirm it, but there is a great possibility that this is what's causing your problem.

EDIT: In case I was unclear, I'm referring to

```
def requires_auth(roles=[Roles.USER]):
```

the default argument is mutable (a list).

Comment: Thank you for the answer however after removing the default argument it appears the decorators still call the wrong function :(

Comment: Default mutable arguments are fine if you don't actually mutate them. Although `def require_auth(roles=(Roles.USER,)):` would be better here

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply your decorators in the right order. This will probably work:

```
@route(...)
@requires_auth(roles=[Roles.Admin])
def get_secret_stuff(request):
    return 42
```

And this probably won't:

```
@requires_auth(roles=[Roles.Admin])
@route(...)
def get_secret_stuff(request):
    return 42
```

Because respectively, these mean

> Wrap `get_secret_stuff` in an authorizer, and use the result as a route

and

> Use `get_secret_stuff` as a route, and wrap the result in an authorizer. The authorizer never makes it into the route.

Comment: Thank you but I tried with only two routes defined and permutated every sensible order of wrappers and it still shows the same issue

Comment: @avoid3d: You need to show us more code in your question - there's nothing wrong with the case you've reduced it to.

Comment: Ok thank you, should I re-edit the question or make a new one. I plan on making a stand alone example